# Expected an intended block error, what am i doing wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know why but i can't run this program in each if or elif there's going to be a couple of functions but i cant seem to be able to make it work, i keep getting the indent error at the elif i==2:

```
menu1=['1-Jugar','2-Ver Top 10','3-Cargar,generar o actualizar archivo Usuarios','0-Salir']
menu2=['1-Reset archivo Usuarios','2-Cargar nuevo arhivo Usuarios','3-Actualizar archivo Usuarios','4-Generar Usuarios aleatorio','0-Volver al Menu Principal']
i=1
while i!=0:
    for k in menu1:
        print (menu1[k],'\n')
    j=1
    i=imput('Por favor ingresar la accion a realizar acorde al numero correspondiente')
    if i==1:
        ...
    elif i==2:
        while j!=0:
            j=imput('Presione 0 para volver al menu principal')
    elif i==3:
        while j!=0:
            for k in menu2:
                print (menu2[k],'\n')
            j=imput('Por favor ingresar la accion a realizar acorde al numero correspondiente')
            if j==1:
                  ...
            elif j==2:
                  ...
            elif j==3:
                  ...
            elif j==4:
                  ...
            elif j==0:
                  ...
            else: 
                  print ('Por favor ingresar un numero valido')
    elif i==0: 
        ...
    else: 
        print ('Por favor ingresar un numero valido')
```

Comment: In your `if i==1` block you need some code or atleast `pass`. Same for other blank `if`, `elif` block

Comment: If you're leaving those conditions blank, add `pass` to them. Those conditions need at least 1 statement inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main issues in your code.

1. Indent. Follow consistent indentation, and make sure you have at least 1 statement inside your conditions
2. You are iterating over the list elements, not over the indices. `menu1[k]` is invalid, because `k` is not an index. If `menu1 = ['hi', 'hello']` then k can take on `'hi'` and `'hello'`, not `0` and `1`.
3. The function you call for taking input is misspelled as `imput`. If you're using python2, use `raw_input`, or `input` for python3.

Fixed your code.

```
#Programa Principal, desde aqui haremos el menu
menu1=['1-Jugar','2-Ver Top 10','3-Cargar,generar o actualizar archivo Usuarios','0-Salir']
menu2=['1-Reset archivo Usuarios','2-Cargar nuevo arhivo Usuarios','3-Actualizar archivo Usuarios','4-Generar Usuarios aleatorio','0-Volver al Menu Principal']
i=1
while i!=0:
    for k in menu1:
        print (k,'\n')
    j=1
    i=input('Por favor ingresar la accion a realizar acorde al numero correspondiente')
    if i==1:
        #Se inicia el juego
        pass
    elif i==2:
        #Se imprime el top 10 y vuelve
        #Aca va el programa de top 10
        while j!=0:
            j=input('Presione 0 para volver al menu principal')
    elif i==3:
        #Va a menuUsuarios
        while j!=0:
            for k in menu2:
                print(k, '\n')
            j=input('Por favor ingresar la accion a realizar acorde al numero correspondiente')
            if j==1:
                #Resetea Usuarios, se borra el anterior
                pass
            elif j==2:
                #Carga nuevo Usuarios, se borra el anterior
                pass
            elif j==3:
                #Permite crear un nuevo novUsuarios y realiza el apareo
                pass
            elif j==4:
                #Genera un Usuarios aleatorio, se borra el anterior
                pass
            elif j==0:
                #Vuelve al menu principal
                pass
            else: 
                #Accion invalida
                print ('Por favor ingresar un numero valido')
    elif i==0: 
        #Como no hace nada sale del programa
        pass
    else: 
        #Accion invalida
        print ('Por favor ingresar un numero valido')
```